# SQL named query not returning any values

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection, named-query

I'm trying to use a named query for my web application, the user is searching for a property by max price, min price, and location. The SQL I was using for this function works perfect but I'm trying to keep my site from being vulnerable from SQL injection. i trued using named queries but I just can't get it to work.

The code I had for the query that works but is vulnerable is as follows:

```
 public static List<Properties> searchProperty(String city, String maxPrice,String minPrice) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();

    List<Properties> list = null;
    try {
        String q = "SELECT p FROM Properties p WHERE p.city = " + "'"+city+"'" + " AND p.price < " + maxPrice + " AND p.price > "+ minPrice;

        TypedQuery<Properties> tq = em.createQuery(q, Properties.class);

        list = tq.getResultList();

        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            list = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        em.clear();
    }

    return list;
}
```

The named query that I can't get working is as follows

```
public static List<Properties> searchProperty(String city, String maxPrice, String minPrice) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    List<Properties> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        list = em.createNamedQuery("Properties.findByCityAndPrice")
                .setParameter("city", city)
                .setParameter("minPrice", minPrice)
                .setParameter("maxPrice", maxPrice)
                .getResultList();

        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            list = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        em.clear();
    }
    return list;
}
```

and

```
   @NamedQuery(name = "Properties.findByLocationAndPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Properties p WHERE p.city = :city AND p.price > :minPrice AND p.price < :maxPrice")})
```

Comment: Your query name is different : `Properties.findByCityAndPrice` != `Properties.findByLocationAndPrice`, and as you are catching and ignoring exceptions, and then return an empty list, you don't notice the problem.

Comment: Also: prices are numbers. Don't use Strings to represent numbers. And never, ever, ever return null from a method returning a List. Just return an empty list. Just as getResultList() does, making your check for null useless. Creating a new ArrayList is also useless. Why do you create one?